# how to pass int variable from list view adapter to activity

Tags: listview, android-arrayadapter

/**each listView item has button when clicked score increase by 1. what code i should add in both adapter and activity to pass this variable (mscore) from adapter to the activity**/

```
public QuestionList(Activity context, List<completeQuestion> questionList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout, questionList);
    this.context = context;
    this.questionList = questionList;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);

    TextView textview = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button ioanswer1 = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer1);


     completequestion1 = questionList.get(position);



    textview.setText(completequestion1.getQuestionI());

    ioanswer1.setText(completequestion1.getQuestionAnswer1());

    mAnswer = completequestion1.getQuestionCorrectAnswer();

   ioanswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            if (mAnswer.equals completequestion1.getQuestionAnswer1()){
                mScore = mScore + 1;

            }
        }
    });


    return listViewItem;
}
```

// thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some properties to your model classes.

First add `Score` property or field to your item class (it seems you're using `completeQuestion`).

Then add a `getItem` method to your adapter.

Then you can call `adapter.getItem(i).getScore()`